# Clear cargo cache before a certain date

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

My cargo cache (`MY_PROJECT/target`) directory has increased to several Gigabytes. For certain build targets there are multiple versions of it, with different SHAs. I'd like to keep the latest entries and delete the ones before a certain date. Is there a command in cargo that clears up cache that are older?

Something to the effect of:

```
cargo clear-cache --before 01/20/2023
cargo clear-cache --older-than 30d
```

Comment: Which "cache" directory are you referring to? The one at `your-project/target` or the ones in `~/.cargo/registry`?

Comment: project/target. i'll clarify in the question.

Answer (score 1):

There is no functionality for this built into `cargo`, beyond `cargo clean` which deletes the entire `target/` directory. There are some third-party tools to do it, such as [`cargo-sweep`](https://crates.io/crates/cargo-sweep) (not a recommendation, I haven't tried it, just an example I remember).

Comment: Another is [cargo-cache](https://crates.io/crates/cargo-cache)